# SFTP Upload Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ssh, laravel-5.1

I’m trying to upload files to my staging server running Linux Ubuntu.

I tried follow everything in this post = https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/ssh . I am on Laravel 5.1.

I configured my `remote.php` like this :

```
'connections' => [
        'production' => [
            'host'      => '45.55.88.88',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'key'       => '/Users/bheng/.ssh/id_rsa', //Try : public | private
            'keytext'   => '',
            'keyphrase' => '******',
            'agent'     => '', //Try : empty | enabled | disabled,
            'timeout'   => 10,
        ],
    ],
```

I tried test it like this in my project :

```
SSH::run('date', function($line) {dd($line); });
```

I kept getting :

> Unable to connect to remote server.

---

I tried it on my Mac OS Terminal

```
sftp root@45.55.88.88
```

It’s working fine, I got

```
sftp> ls
Desktop       Documents     Downloads     Music         Pictures      Public        Templates     Videos        dead.letter
```

---

What did I do wrong or forget ? What elses should I try ?

Do I need to do anything on my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ?

Can someone please help me out if you’re done this before ?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the connection in case it's not using the correct settings, and see if that helps:

```
SSH::into('production')->run('date', function($line) {dd($line); });
```

The only other things I would recommend are:

- Verify that your key is accessible from your code
- Correct passphrase is being used
- Double-check any other connection settings